# Photoshop: Smoke with semi-transparent background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background

I'm attempting to make a transparent logo that uses a smoke effect. I used the tutorial found here to do so: [Photoshop CS5: Setting a black background to transparent](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/photoshop-cs5-setting-a-black-background-to-transparent)

However, I am having issues as the image continues to have a faint white background, although it's not entirely opaque. I can't figure out how to get rid of this, and I found that if I did the same steps but with the smoke in black, it turned out to have a dark hue to it.

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can get rid of this? Even if there is a better means right from the beginning. Below is the image I started with:

[image]

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: seems that you provided link to the solution and not to the tutorial itself...

Answer (score 5):

Like @Ilan said, you seem to have tutorial right there on how to get rid of the background, however here's another way of doing it and a way to get rid of the white part.

Since it's a black and white image, you could:

*I'm assuming that this is one flat image you are working with.*

1. Fill a new layer with white
2. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and click the `Layer mask` icon.

   - That way the `Layer mask` will be filled with black. [image]
3. Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd>  key and click the layer mask thumbnail.

   - This gets you inside the layer mask.
4. Paste the image into the document now <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> [image]
5. Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd>  key and click the layer mask thumbnail again.

   - This gets you out of the layer mask. [image]
6. Use levels to get rid of the extra white part <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>.

   - Start moving the black arrow to the right, until the extra white bits disappear
   - In some cases you might want to move the middle arrow as well, but I didn't find it necessary in this case.
   - Note that I have that red background there so that you can easily see the edge. [image]

[image]

I'm not posting the png, so that you don't feel temptation to just use that.

Comment: I got it to work perfectly, thank you so much!