# PS - Save for Web - PNG24 not full transparent in Browser

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, png

i tried to export my photoshop mockup file as PNG-24 with transparency, but it doesn't work. Here are some Screenshots what looks like:

[image: Photoshop Artboard Settings]

[image: Channels]

[image: Save for Web Dialog]

### Preview in Chrome

[image: Body Background: #fff]

[image: Body Background: Green]

Not full transparent, why? and how can i solve this?
And another question... How can i improve the file size with PNG-24? 2MB is too big. But when i use PNG-8 the keyboard and mouse shadow looks like too blurry...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you checked that it should be transparent? For example placing it against the colored bg in PS

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. 100% transparent areas within a PNG24 remain fully transparent when I export them.  Also the file size problem is really another question altogether. Probably best to ask this separately.

Comment: Are you asking why the shadow from the mouse fades to a black-white blend instead of a black-green blend?

Comment: @BillyKerr i am using this mockup: https://www.anthonyboyd.graphics/mockups/front-view-imac-pro-mockup/ 
could you replicate my problem?

Comment: The shadow layer appears to be the problem. It's not fully transparent. Try switching it off and on, and you will see.

Comment: @BillyKerr OK, thank you... do you have any idea how I can best solve this? I wanted to keep the shadow on a transparent background, otherwise it looks so unrealistic on the website...

Comment: You could switch off the shadow layer, or perhaps make your own shadow layer that isn't filled light grey.

Comment: If the shadow layer is that other raster layer, activate the layer, Cmd+A, Cmd+C, add layer mask, Alt+Click layer masks thumbnail, Cmd+V, Cmd+L and adjust the upper dials until the white stuff disappears.

Comment: Took some digging, but I found a question with a similar question and a similar answer that I tried to condense in my comment above https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29612/2332