# What is the easiest way to make the background transparent in this image?

Tags: print-design, color-conversion

[image: Shirt Logo]

Hello.  I am a volunteer coach for my 7 year old daughter's soccer team. I want to make a coach's shirt with a logo on it and use the image below.  I do this myself typically and do the iron on myself as well.  However, I don't want it to be on an all black background.  Would like for it to be transparent.  I'm not really literate in the photo editing software that came with the computer and don't have access to photoshop.  Not sure my skill level would do it even if I did ahve photoshop LOL.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to GD.  It would be hard pressed for you to be able to do this on your own but you could always try with [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/). I would recommend contacting a printer that provides DTG printing and they may already have something for you or can handle the job.

Comment: Here is a solution with Photoshop: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/photoshop-cs5-setting-a-black-background-to-transparent

Comment: I'm not asking for free work and right now, all I have is MSPaint. IF someone can recommend software that isn't real expensive that would be easy for a novice to use, that's kind of where I am going.

Just trying to get ideas about how I can get what I am looking for. I am doing all the work myself, including the transfer onto a shirt. I got the image from a free image site to ensure I wasn't violating any laws.

Comment: The truth of the matter is most here are professionals who use professional software. There's not many here that are going to be in a position to recommend much at a cheaper price point and be able to explain how to use it. You can try GIMP, it's free and is designed to edit raster images (photographs).

Comment: In addition, for t shirts the image may not be suitable at all depending upon the production methods used. The only real option for a photograph may be heat sublimation (iron-on). Be aware, the reason that image appears dynamic is due to the high contrast between the black and the flames. Removing the black is going to "dull" the image considerably.

Comment: Oh, thanks Scott and I apologize.  I was google searching and this forum came up.  I am planning doing an iron on.  Just trying to be a little creative for my 6 and 7 year old's.  I'm sorry I posted the question in the wrong place.  Thanks for the help and I'll check out GIMP.

Comment: No problem at all. I just wanted to point out that many here won't have much experience with "home user" software. You're best bet here.. is to ask how to do things with GIMP.. and then [go grab GIMP here](http://www.gimp.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you haven't already used up the free trial of Photoshop CS6 there will be one available for you at the [Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/downloads.html).

Once you have downloaded and installed the 30 day free trial you can follow [this very easy tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrDgTQZhCaY) on how to remove black or white backgrounds with an example image very similar to yours.

**Be aware though:** In the example you have above there are black areas of the football which you don't want faded out, therefore you need to separate the actual football to another layer to not have it affected by the "black-background-removal-procedure". This is probably easiest done with the *Oval marque tool*, drag to select the football using the tool then right click and select "*Copy selection to new layer*" (or similar wording). Give it a try, and if it turns out the way you want it immediately then great, but if not then give YouTube another try to find other tutorials on how to remove backgrounds.

Good luck!