# How to make borders that look like clouds?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

I have Gimp and Photoshop, so any of the two could be useful to me.

I have an image, I would like to use it to create a cloud pattern that uses the borders of the image, this is, an image of clouds that to some extent have the original shapes of the borders in the original image.

AFAIK clouds can be rendered in both, Gimp and Photoshop, but those are random clouds, not based on an image, which is what I want to do.

I do also have pictures of clouds in case that helps.

Comment: Can you maybe sketch what you really want to do? It's a bit hard to understand. Are you looking into procedurally generating clouds?

Comment: OK, let's say that I have a picture of a sculpture, for instance David from Michelangelo. And that I have a picture of clouds, just clouds, no sky, but they have a cloudy shape. I'd like to use the borders in the first image (like with Sobel or gaussian something similar) and the border pattern in the second one. To make clouds that have the shape of the sculpture. Is that more clear? It may be very hard or impossible to do, I don't know that.

Comment: That's gonna be tough, but I don't know a lot of programs in this field either. Thanks for your explanation, makes more sense now!

Comment: similar to : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/effective-way-to-cut-out-clouds-in-photoshop

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your picture, there are a few ways you could try to tackle this if I'm even understanding right.

Basically what I think you want to do is use the clouds as a **layer mask** over a sculpture. Try finding a tutorial on layer masks or tinkering with them in photoshop. What you'll ultimately want to do is probably increase the **contrast** and/or **levels** of the sculpture and then apply the clouds as a layer mask over it perhaps using the **warp** or **puppet warp** to manipulate the clouds in a seemingly curved shape a little.